# How to restore g++/gcc compiling messages

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm using CentOS 6.5. When I do a make, I typically see the full gcc/g++ commands that the Makefile is executing, like

```
...
 gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/opt/emacs/emacs-24.3/lib -I../src -I/opt/emacs/emacs-24.3/src      -g3 -O2 -MT pthread_sigmask.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/pthread_sigmask.Tpo -c -o pthread_sigmask.o pthread_sigmask.c
...
```

But in some systems, I only see:

```
$ make

Building test1.o...

Building test2.o...
```

...

Is it possible to change the "Building ..." messages back to the full gcc/g++ command output?

Comment: Did you type `make -s` or have an alias somewhere? What about `@` characters in the makefile? Without more context it's hard to say what's going on.

Comment: With some build systems, `make VERBOSE=1` is more verbose...

Answer (score 1):

The output that you see when you run `make` with a given makefile
depends on how the makefile is written. You will see the
output that the author of the makefile wants you to see.

If a command in a recipe in the makefile is prefixed with `@`,
then `make` will not echo the command. So if my makefile is, e.g.

```
foobar: foobar.o
    gcc -o $@ $<

foobar.o: foobar.c
    gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

then the output of `make` will be:

```
gcc -c -o foobar.o foobar.c 
gcc -o foobar foobar.o
```

But if I change the makefile to:

```
foobar: foobar.o
    @echo "Linking foobar"
    @gcc -o $@ $<

foobar.o: foobar.c
    @echo "Compiling foobar"
    @gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

then the output becomes:

```
Compiling foobar
Linking foobar
```

So to see the output that you would prefer to see you will have to edit the
makefile, removing the `@`-prefixes from the commands you expect to see
and deleting entirely the commands that print the "Building..." messages.

At least, this is what you would need to do if the makefiles that bother
you in this way build the target using recipes that directly invoke gcc/g++. It
is possible that they build their targets using recipes that invoke some intermediate
tool that doesn't echo the compiler commands and instead emits the "Building..."
messages. Without seeing the makefile(s) I can't say.